# How to create textbox which accept links and text using angular

Tags: angular

I have to create a textbox like Add a comments like stack overflow which accept links as well as text

Comment: Actually, links are text as well, so you should be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use textarea html like this

```
<textarea>

</textarea>
```